# set value while debugging is not enabled

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Code 64bit and trying to change a value during my debug session.

I tried using the set value menu option to change a value but it's disabled. I've got the PHP Debugging extension installed and have no problems stepping through the code. I tried the debug console but can't seem to do any unset's there.  I have `$_SERVER` values I would like to clear.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Edit server values while the server is stopped?

Comment: Yes.  I wish to clear some $_SERVER variables.  But even locally defined variables are not editable.  Online documentation says to right click on the variable and choose Set Value.  But it's not enabled for me.  Thank you.

Comment: I got it ifconfig.  In the debug console, it's as easy as typing $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = "".  Sorry for making this more difficult than it should have been.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using the debug console allows you to change the values.